# C++ casting bool to int - standard

Tags: c++, casting, boolean

I am interrested wheather standard says anything about possible values of `bool` type type after casting it to `integer` type.

For example following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool someValue=false;
    *((int*)(&someValue)) = 50;

    cout << someValue << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

prints 1 even though it's forced to store value 50. Does standard specify anything about it? Or is compiler generating some method for type bool as:

```
operator int(){
    return myValue !=0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Also why is casting like following:

```
reinterpret_cast<int>(someValue) = 50;
```

forbidden with error

> error: invalid cast from type 'bool' to type 'int'

(For all above I user GCC 5.1 compiler.)

Comment: AFAIK your code exhibits UB as it goes against strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Also while writing into `someValue` you are crossing the memory requirements for `bool`

Comment: Why would you even *try* to do these things?

Comment: This code is **not** casting a `bool` to an `int`. That would be `(int)someValue`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I am not saying, that I am casting. I am saying, that I am forcing it to store value. Although truly in question I am Interested in casting mainly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I just wanted to know how it's represented in low level.

Comment: So change your title.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't see this useful. Question is correct. I said, that in code I am forcing it to store. I am still interested in how this works low level

Comment: [Integer and bool conversion rules on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you are using it exhibits UB, because you write outside of the bool variable's boundaries AND you break strict aliasing rule.

However, if you have a bool and want to use it as a an int (this usually happens when you want to index into an array based on some condition), the standard mandates that a `true` bool converts into `1` and `false` bool converts into `0`, no matter what (UB obviously excluded).

For example, this is guaranteed to output `52` as long as `should_add == true`.

```
int main(){
    int arr[] = {0, 10};
    bool should_add = 123;
    int result = 42 + arr[should_add];
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This line `*((int*)(&someValue)) = 50;` is  at least non standard. The implementation could use a lesser rank for bool (say 1 or 2 bytes) that for int (say 4 bytes). In that case, you would write past the variable possibly erasing an other variable.

And anyway, as you were said in comment, thanks to the *strict aliasing rule* almost any access through a casted pointer can be seen as Undefined Behaviour by a compiler. The only almost *legal* one (for the strict aliasing rule) would be:

```
*((char *) &someValue) = 50;
```

on a little endian system, and

```
*(((char *) &someValue) + sizeof(bool) - 1) = 50;
```

on a big endian one (byte access has still not be forbidden).

Anyway, as the representation of bool is not specified by the standard directly writing something in a bool can lead to true or false depending on implementation. For example an implementation could considere only the lowest level bit (true if val&1 is 1, else 0), another one could considere all bits (true for any non 0 value, false for only 0). The only thing that standard says is that a *conversion* of a 0 leads to false and of a non 0 leads to true.

---

But was is mandated by standard is the conversion from bool to int:

> 4.5 Integral promotions [conv.prom]
>
> ...
> A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true
>   becoming one.

So this fully explains that displaying a bool can only give 0 or 1 - even if as the previous operation invoked UB, anything could have happen here including this display

```
You invoked Undefined Behaviour - shame on you
```

Comment: Sorry, but the endian-related stuff does not make sense. Either operation is valid on any system, and both end the lifetime of the boolean object. And if ` sizeof(bool>2)`, you can also write a `char` to the bytes in the middle.

Comment: Also, since writing a `char` ends the lifetime of the `bool`, you can't say it's `true` or `false`. That memory now holds a `char`, so its values are `CHAR_MIN...CHAR_MAX`. Attempting to read that as a `bool` is again Undefined Behavior by the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: That's the other way around, and specifically allowed for thing like `memcpy`  to work. IOW, you can copy a bool to a bool, using `char[sizeof(bool)]` as the intermediate representation.

Comment: @MSalters: I think that one can read the bytes of the representation from any object by aliasing its address to a `char *`, and hoped that it could also be used to change the bytes of an object. Of course the result depends on the representation of the type for the implementation, But I hoped that it was at least *legal* and did not automatically end the object lifetime

Comment: Well, the first part is true. That's the second half of `memcpy`, after all. The chief problem is how the lifetime of POD objects is described. With memcpy, the old POD object at the destination dies when its memory is overwritten by `memcpy`. After that object is dead, its type becomes meaningless. However, there could still be expressions that refer to that storage location, and _those_ also have a type. E.g. `*pMyBool`. Now if you memcpy one bool over another, expressions like `*pMyBool` remain valid  - there was a bool there, there still is, it just happens to be another instance.

Comment: @MSalters: Thank you for your explainations. I miss the K&R C before the strict aliasing rule, but at least you make it more clear :-)